# Defining a map from a tensor product to an $R$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

If $A,B,C$ be $R$-algebra such that $C$ is commutative and $f:A \rightarrow C$ and $g:B \rightarrow C$ be $R$-algebra maps how can I construct an $R$-algebra map $A \otimes_{R} B \rightarrow C$? if C is not-commutative what happen?

Answer (score 1):

In general $R$-algebra maps $A\otimes_R B\to C$ correspond canonically to pairs of $R$-algebra maps $f: A\to C$, $g: B\to C$ such that the images of $f$ and $g$ commute with one another. When $C$ is commutative that condition is of course automatic, otherwise it has to be enforced.

For instance, if $K$ is a field, although there are many $K$-algebra maps $M_2(K)\to M_2(K)$, there does not exist a $K$-algebra map $M_2(K)\otimes_K M_2(K)\to M_2(K)$ because all morphisms $M_2(K)\to M_2(K)$ are surjective, and therefore two of them cannot have commuting images.